# Change this code to not construct the path from user-controlled data in SonarQube S3 error

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, sonarqube

I have the below line of code, and I am not getting any issues here. So I'm hoping someone can help me determine if it is an issue or false positive showing in Sonar.

```
$fileContent = $this->getContent($filepath);
$s3Destination = $basedir . "/" . $targetpath;
$status = $s3Disk->put($s3Destination, $fileContent);
```

As per example given in Sonar, tried to change code to below line:

```
$fileContent = (string) $this->getContent($filepath);
$s3Destination = (string) $basedir . "/" . $targetpath;
$status = $s3Disk->put($s3Destination, $fileContent);
```

Can someone help me here?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @MátyásGrőger error is "Change this code to not construct the path from user-controlled data"

Comment: @MátyásGrőger any idea about error?

Comment: Check this out https://community.sonarsource.com/t/change-this-code-to-not-construct-the-url-from-user-controlled-data/34393

Answer (score 0):

Added this method to fix the issue:

```
public function sanitizePath($url)
{
    return strip_tags(
        str_replace(
            '../',
            '',
            $url
        )
    );
}
```